# How to resolve a registered type with Unity without the Container object?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

In my productive code, I've got some code like the following. I would like to achieve, that in the method AddOrder, the instance which is currently created via `new Connector()` is created via Unity type resolving.

```
public class SampleOrderDto { }

public class SampleUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IConnector _connector;

    public SampleUnitOfWork(IConnector connector) { _connector = connector; }

    public void DoSomething() { }

    public void Dispose() { _connector.Dispose(); }
}

public interface IConnector : IDisposable { }

public class Connector : IConnector
{
    public void Dispose() { }
}

public class SampleDataSourceAccessor<T> where T : new()
{
    public void AddOrder(SampleOrderDto order)
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = new SampleUnitOfWork(new Connector()))
        {
            unitOfWork.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

In the Main method, I would register the IConnector interface with the Connector class:

```
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IConnector, Connector>();
```

But what should I do to resolve the type at the place where it is needed? Because at the place where the type instance is needed, I don't have the container object.

Comment: When you need an `IConnector`, just add one to the constructor of the class where you need it. That's basically how DI works.

Comment: @DavidG Sorry, I don't understand. I want that not always the IConnector interface is resolved with the Connector class, but – during testing – instead with another class, for instance ConnectorMock. I can't put that registration in the SampleDataSourceAccessor class, it should be in the Main method, am I right? Please consider that I'm new to DI and Unity and that I don't understand everything so far.

Comment: This looks like you would need to apply factory pattern here